# Нажать кнопку в другом приложении, свернутом в трей

Tags: c++

Использовал:

```
SendMessage((HWND)hwnd, BM_CLICK, (WPARAM)NULL, (LPARAM)NULL);
```

Пока другое приложении не свернуто в трей - все работает. Если свернуть - не работает. Как посылать сообщение в приложение, свернутой в трей?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, общего метода нет. Обычно приложение просто сначала разворачивают из трея, а потом уж отправляют нужные нажатия на кнопки.

Comment: Помогло USESHOWWINDOW

Comment: @MikeNew: Тогда имеет смысл написать как ответ.